# Having trouble using a coroutine and event together in Discord.py

Tags: python, events, flask, coroutine

I'm a novice Python programmer. I wrote a bot that does a few cool things in Discord. One of these things is send and receive text messages using Twilio. The receiving part is giving me some trouble.

Below is the basis of my receive functions. An event is called by the HTTP request Twilio makes to my server, which SHOULD call a function to message the users in Discord.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def smsResponse():
    text = request.form['Body']
    smsFrom = request.form['From']
    print ("Message received: \"" + text + "\" from " + smsFrom)
    await incomingSms(text, smsFrom)

async def incomingSms(text, number):
    await discordMessage(TEXT_CHANNEL, "Incoming SMS from " + number + ": \"" + text + "\"")
```

The problem is to send a message in Discord I would have to use a function defined with async. This would mean the call to the function inside the event would need an "await", but this means the event would also have to be defined with async, so instead...

```
async def smsResponse():
```

But I can't do this because it gives me a type error whenever the event is called:

```
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
```

What is a good way around this? Thanks for any info!

Comment: Why do you need to do this asynchronously? Flask doesn't support asyncio. You'd have to schedule `incomingSms` with the event loop yourself. That won't really give you any benefits over a synchronous version.